# execute workflow on feild change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a list of proposals and I want to trigger a workflow based on if the status goes from Active or Submitted to Archived

I created a workflow with an if status = archived but It will trigger the workflow if someone makes an edit to an archived entry

Is there anyway to have it trigger based off the change in status rather than just what the status is set to?

Answer (score 1):

Create another column to check against. It can be a simple choice column called Complete with options Yes and No, where no is the default. On your workflow, you check if the status is archived and complete equals no. Then when done, you set complete equal to yes and the workflow won't fire on edits after that.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer.  Create flags to set from your workflows because they will always run on change if you make them.